# How to Debug a React Native App Running on Mac as a Device

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am developing a React Native app and have configured it to run **directly on my Mac as an iOS device**.

**My Mac serves as the device to run the application**

[image: Here's a screenshot of how I've set it up using Xcode:]

This approach allows me to debug my app using Xcode's powerful tools, avoiding the slower iOS emulators.  Additionally, my app requires Bluetooth functionality, which is unsupported by iOS and Android emulators.

However, **I'm facing a challenge in opening the React Native developer menu (dev tools)** while the app is running on my Mac as a device.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

- I tried shaking my mac, as it typically triggers the developer
  menu on physical iOS devices or in the simulator. However, shaking my
  Mac does not activate the developer menu.
- I've looked for keyboard shortcuts, but I have not found any specific
  shortcuts to open the developer menu when the app runs on a Mac as a
  device.
- I came across the **react-native-invoke-app** library and attempted
  to use the **InvokeApp.openDeveloperMenu()** method.  Here are the steps
  I took:

  Installed the library: **npm install react-native-invoke-app**
  Imported it:

  `import InvokeApp from 'react-native-invoke-app';`

  Added a button to my app to open the React Native dev tools:

  `<Button text="Open React Native Dev Tools" onPress={() => InvokeApp.openDeveloperMenu()} />`

  However, this approach resulted in an error.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error message:]

I'm seeking advice on how I can effectively open the React Native developer menu while my app is running on my Mac as a device. Being able to access the developer menu is crucial for debugging and inspecting my app during development.
Are there any workarounds, undocumented methods, or third-party libraries that might help achieve this?

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches that the community might have. Thank you!

Comment: Shaking the device should work. Did you check the xcode build is an debug build?

Comment: Apologize if my question was not clear. Just to clarify, my Mac serves as the device running the application. However, shaking my Mac did not have any effect on the results

Comment: You mean you are using react native simulator, so shaking the Mac wont help.

In this case focus the simulator and press cmd+d should open the menu.
If not check there is another short cut defined (e.g. start simulator screen recording ).

Or just press "d" when metrobundler windows is focused.

Comment: I don't use the React Native simulator. There is an option in Xcode to run my project on my Mac's operating system and use my Mac as an iOS device. Mac can run apps from the App Store like an iPhone because it has an iOS operating system. Please take a look at my first screenshot. There is an option to choose 'My Mac,' and then the application runs on the Mac's operating system. I don't want to use an emulator because Bluetooth is not enabled in the emulator. However, running my app on the Mac as a device allows my app to use the Mac's Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an apple silicon you can:

1. Start the App
2. Focus the metro bundler window
3. Press "d"

[image]

**EDIT:**

1. npx react-native@latest init TestRNProject
2. yarn
3. npx pod-install
4. Open /ios/TestRNProject.xcworkspace/ with xcode
5. Select the device to compile/run for
6. Press the run button or CMD+R

Comment: Hi, thank you. It didn't work for me with my app. I am pressing 'd,' and I see the log in the Metro: 'info Opening developer menu...' but the developer menu is not opening, and all the app logs continue to appear in the Metro window. I want to try opening a new React Native app and check if this issue also occurs there, or if it's a problem specific to my app. I will update you.

Comment: Create a new project with ```npx react-native@latest init TestRNProject``` and try to open the menu.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you ran your demo app using an Apple Silicon Mac?